# Mi formula regresa este error: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python

Mi función no regresa los valores que debería regresar. Me regresa None, el bmi calculado si esta regresando un valor útil pues lo puedo usar en otras ocasiones.

Escribo mi función aquí:

```
def percent_macros(bmi,f):

    if bmi < 18.5:
        if f == 1:
            x = .50
            y = .25
            z = .25
            return x,y,z

        if f == 2:
            x = .52
            y = .23
            z = .25
            return x,y,z

        if f == 3:
            x = .53
            y = .22
            z = .25
            return x,y,z

        if f == 4:
            x = .55
            y = .20
            z = .25
            return x,y,z

    elif 18.5 < bmi <25:
        if f == 1:
            x = .48
            y = .25
            z = .27
            return x,y,z

        if f == 2:
            x = .49
            y = .24
            z = .27
            return x,y,z

        if f == 3:
            x = .51
            y = .22
            z = .27
            return x,y,z

        if f == 4:
            x = .52
            y = .21
            z = .27
            return x,y,z

    else:
        if f == 1:
            x = .45
            y = .25
            z = .30
            return x,y,z

        if f == 2:
            x = .47
            y = .23
            z = .30
            return x,y,z

        if f == 3:
            x = .48
            y = .22
            z = .30
            return x,y,z

        if f == 4:
            x = .50
            y = .20
            z = .30
            return x,y,z
```

Nota: Si hago que el bmi sea mayor a 25 si me regresa los valores correctos, por lo que la parte de else si esta funcionando.
Soy principiante entonces si tienen una recomendación para llegara  esta solución por un método mas corto o mas eficiente, me encantaría.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: El error, lo que te dice es que la función esta retornando `None` en vez de valores x, y, z. Revisa la lógica, hay alguna situación que hace que no se pase por ninguno de los `return` que has definido.

Comment: El valor de `bmi` no es el problema (cualquier valor es cubierto por el `if-elif-else`), el problema en principio es `f`, ten en cuenta que si  `f` no es 1, 2, 3 o 4 la función retorna `None` siempre (valor por defecto que retorna cualquier función en Python) independientemente de `bmi`. Por cierto, no encadenes if si son excluyentes, es muy ineficiente, usa `elif`. Revisa la lógica como comenta Patricio. debes cubrir la posibilidad de que `f` no esté en el rango `1 <= f <= 4` o **que no sea entero** (`2.1` no cae tampoco en nigún `if`)

Answer (score 0):

lo primero es que la función te devuelve `None` o lo que es lo mismo, no ha alcanzado
ninguna condición, para depurar primero debés saber que es lo que ve la función, para ello
tenemos diversas vias y solo voy a mencionar unas pocas.

Al mismo tiempo pides una forma "mas eficiente o mas corta" voy a reescribir un poco de código para
evitar tanto if anidado, en su lugar usaremos listas.
He modificado la condición de igualdad, tal y como lo tienes, si bmi es 18.5 o 25 entrarían
dentro del else.

```
def percent_macros(bmi,f):
    assert isinstance(bmi, (float, int)), 'bmi no es un número' # comprobamos que  bmi es un número
    assert isinstance(f, int), 'f no es un número entero' # comprobamos que  f es un número entero
    assert f in (1, 2, 3, 4) # comprobamos que f esta en el rango 1, 4 también podría ser range(1, 5)
    # Las comprobaciones anteriores nos permiten depurar que los datos que recibe son los correctos
    f = f -1 # como vamos a usar listas estas empiezan por 0 de modo que reducimos en 1 el número de f

    if bmi <= 18.5:
        percent = (
            (.50, .25, .25),   # El resultado si f es 1        
            (.52, .23, .25),   # El resultado si f es 2             
            (.53, .22, .25),   # El resultado si f es 3         
            (.55, .20, .25),   # El resultado si f es 4
            )        
    elif bmi <= 25: 
        percent = (
            (.48, .25, .27),   # El resultado si f es 1         
            (.49, .24, .27),   # El resultado si f es 2             
            (.51, .22, .27),   # El resultado si f es 3             
            (.52, .21, .27),   # El resultado si f es 4
            )            
    else:
        percent = (
            (.45, .25, .30),   # El resultado si f es 1         
            (.47, .23, .30),   # El resultado si f es 2             
            (.48, .22, .30),   # El resultado si f es 3             
            (.50, .20, .30),   # El resultado si f es 4
            )
    return percent[f]
```

Como puedes ver el cçodigo es mas legible y fácil de seguir y las comprobaciones antes de los if
te permiten saber de donde procede el error.
Espero que te sirva